# React Navigation - Border Top Radius is added when going back from modal screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am using React Navigation on my expo application.

I have a "Categories list" Screen and an "Add Category" Screen that is set on the presentation modal option.

In the Categories List Screen, when I am clicking on the top right button to add a Category the modal is open up.

In the modal, clicking on the top left button redirect you back/ close the modal.

In the second picture, after I closed the modal, you can notice the border-top radius, but after a second the border-top radius disappear.

How can I remove this border-top radius?
I already see similar Issues on the GitHub repository of the Library but all of them are closed because they are saying :

> Modals are intended to be used at root. It's not proper UX to have
> them nested inside tab navigator.
>
> While it's not needed visually, the borderRadius is intentionally
> added for performance reasons. We won't change it since it works fine
> with its intended usage.
>
> If you really want modals inside tab navigator for some reason, you
> can provide a custom cardStyleInterpolator which uses different border
> radius.

So today, in 2023, soon 2024, when using an Expo or React native app, and wants to handle modal view, how can we achieve that?

[image: View without the issue]
[image: Modal Opened]
[image: Modal Closed]

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    options={{
      presentation: "modal",
    }}
    name="AddCategory"
    component={AddEditCategory}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Using :

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.14",
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put a View inside the Modal (right after its declaration) with this style:

```
 <Modal>
          <View
            style={{
              borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
              borderTopRightRadius: 0,
              overflow: 'hidden',
            }}
          >
      </Modal>
```

Comment: Not working for me , still have the radius